# How to set the Configuration up for "Text Editor"?

Tags: text-editor

Is there a way to set the default tabs, language etc, of the built in "Text Editor", I'd like to change the tab length , that is defaulted to 8, to 2.
Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1203279/edit) your question and what you mean by language. Do you mean English spell check, typing in Japanese, or syntax highlighting for java or python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Text Editor` (gedit).

Open Preferences.

[image]

Select Editor tab.

Set Tab width...

[image]

Go to Tools menu to set language.

[image]

Comment: My Nautilus preferences are somewhere else. Feel free to use the screenshot I have in my answer in your answer. I will delete my answer then.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for the offer! But your screenshot shows off an older `gedit`, and since we don't know what OP has, we'll just leave it be. And... do your 19.xx update :-)

Comment: Indeed, I am sticking to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which stuck some of the menu items in this weird place for some apps. I will highlight the version number in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## The Preference is somewhere else in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

In Ubuntu 18.04, the preference menu item is hidden in the top panel:

[image]

Once in preference, go to the Editor tab, and change the tab width.

## Language...

### Spellcheck

The Spellcheck language is under the **Tools** menu which is under the <kbd>≡</kbd> menu button.

### Foreign Language input

If you need to add a different language to write in, such as Japanese, or Gujrati, you will have to do that at the OS settings level: **Settings > Regions and Languages > Input Sources**.

### Programming language syntax highlighting

Most programming languages are automatically highlighted in **Text Editor**.

Hope this helps